# Как реализовать поиск совпадения строк в таблицах?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.5

Есть таблица 1 со строковыми полями. f1, f2, f3, f4,....

Есть таблица 2 с json массивами f1, f2, f3, f4,...

Пример данных:

```
    Таблица 1:
    -- Строка 1
    f1 = 'AB'
    f2 = 'CD'
    f3 = 'AD'
    f4 = 'P'
    -- Строка 2
    f1 = 'AA'
    f2 = 'BB'
    f3 = 'CC'
    f4 = null


    Таблица 2:
    f1 = ['AA', 'BB']
    f2 = ['CD', 'BB']
    f3 = ['AD', 'CC', 'BB']
    f4 = ['AB', 'CD', null]
```

Хочется найти строку из таблицы 1, зная строку из таблицы 2. Конечно, я могу сделать это средствами php, но хочется одним запросом получить результат. Поиск должен производиться так: `where t1 in ['AA', 'BB']`

Совпадения должны учитываться по всем колонкам. Никак не могу сообразить, как строить запрос и будет ли работать null.

Comment: Образцы заполненных таблиц и что именно должно быть найдено приведите в вопросе (т.е. create table и insert заполняющий таблицы), можно на sqlfiddle.com. А вообще, на вскидку, посмотрев в гугле список функций postgresql работающих с json подозреваю, что `json_array_elements` именно то, что нужно

Comment: Я json для примера привел. Если коротко, у меня будет одна таблица с данными и одна таблица с условиями. Я хочу находить данные из первой таблицы по условиям из второй и наоборот. Не знаю, как лучше организовать. Ситуацию усложняет то, что этот запрос должен выполняться не слишком долго.

Comment: Еще настораживает то, что select 1 where null in (null) не срабатывает, потому остается открытым вопрос о нахождении null значений.

Comment: Еще дополнение. `select '"BB"' in (select json_array_elements('["AA","BB","CC",null]')::text);` возвращает true, но кавычек то не должно быть. Без кавычек false

Comment: json_array_elements_text Помог